# Getting value from iframe to iframe

Tags: javascript

I have two iframes in the document **movie.htm**:

```
<iframe id='movies' class='top' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

and

```
<iframe src="moviesearch.htm" class="bottom" frameborder="0">
```

Within **moviesearch.htm** there is an input tag

```
<input id="search_str" type="text">
```

I was wondering how I access this value (contained in **moviesearch.htm**) using JavaScript in the document **movie.htm**.

As the user is typing the field continuously it would require that the value be updated real-time within **movie.htm**.

How would I achieve this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

If both pages are in the same domain, you'll be able to `iframe.contentDocument`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/iframe#p-contentDocument

Comment: It works in all browsers too. contentDocument may be a safer bet. I just like doing it the HTML5 way :P

Answer (score 0):

postMessage.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage

movie.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Current value:<div id="updatedvalue"></div>
<iframe src="moviesearch.htm"></iframe>

</body>
<script>
window.addEventListener
    ("message", function(e) {
    document.getElementById("updatedvalue").innerHTML = e.data;
    }, true);


</script>
</html>
```

moviesearch.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" onkeyup="sendMessage(this.value)">
</body>
<script>
function sendMessage(message) {
    window.parent.postMessage(message, "*");
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't that a [security risk](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage#Security_concerns)? Anybody could (hidden) load movie.htm and post a message with a XSS attack?! Never use innerHTML, especially if you try to make it with HTML5 :)

Comment: Yeah, for the sake of example, I didn't scan for the local domain (thus the '*'). You need to for security reasons though.